# How do I configure possitiveSSL on embedded yaws?

Tags: erlang, ssl-certificate, yaws

I bought a possitiveSSL certificate from ComodoSSL

these are the files I was received from them

```
Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
Your PositiveSSL Certificate - domain_com.crt
```

How do I replace these files with the following embedded yaws configuration?

```
{ssl,[{keyfile, "/home/user/Develop/yaws-2.0.2/etc/yaws/yaws-key.pem"},
          {certfile, "/home/user/Develop/yaws-2.0.2/etc/yaws/yaws-cert.pem"},
          {depth,0},{dhfile,"/home/yser/Develop/yaws-2.0.2/etc/yaws/dhparams.pem"}]},
```

Comment: Yaws uses Erlang SSL, so my advice is to consult the [ssl man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html). I've also added the #erlang tag to your question.

Comment: I already have solved the problem, I have posted my experience as an answer. thank you))

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by combining the following files into one `filename.crt`:

```
Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
Your PositiveSSL Certificate - domain_com.crt
```

Then I added the key signature I used to request the ssl certificate into a `file.key` file.

so the result is something like this:

```
{port, 443}
{ssl,[{keyfile, "/home/file.key"},
          {certfile, "/home/filename.crt"},
          {depth,0}]}
```